# How to add actuator, controller and action to series of objects?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have a lot of object in my BGE environment. I can select them easily by using regular expression. All of them, also have action with specific name, too.
Now I want to add them to my game, by python script. Is there any way to add actuator, controller and set action programmatically?

Comment: Is it possible??

Comment: Yes see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/manipulate-bge-logic-bricks-through-python

Comment: My main problem is about adding action actuator. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I didn't see any code example about that.

Comment: I've added an actuator example to the [previous question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2206/935) recommended by @stacker

Comment: @sambler Thanks. how to set property of action? for example, how to set playing mode or start-end frame number with python?

Comment: @sambler I found how to set property and i will post complete code later.